# Error when attempting to @use sass variables with node-sass

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to put a shared constant in a single `.sass` file and then import this in other `.sass` files but I'm getting `Invalid CSS` errors. currently, my code is structured as:

```
// src/react/stylesheets/_constants.sass

$uiAccent: black
```

and

```
// src/react/stylesheets/myComponent.sass

@use "constants"

//...

.item
    border-bottom: 1px solid
    border-color: constants.$uiAccent
```

I modeled this based on the official sass [guide for @use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) and as best I can tell, my structure is identical to theirs.

When I run `sass --watch src/react/stylesheets/:src/react/css/` to convert my sass files to css ones, I get `error src/react/stylesheets/myComponent.sass (Line 12: Invalid CSS after "constants": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$uiAccent")`

I've tried moving the variable into the file where it was used (so I just removed the `@use` line and copied in the variable assignment), and it all works fine, so I don't think it's an issue with the sass to css conversion, and I've made sure all my files are `.sass` and not `.scss` because I've seen someone have a similar problem with `.scss` files.

I found [this github issue](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-scss/issues/150) which looks similar, especially the [related one about node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1192) but these were both from 2015 so I have a hard time believing that such a common feature has been broken for 5 years.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just `@import` the file and use `$uiAccent` directly?

Comment: I read here [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) that `@import` is discouraged and `@use` is now preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I realized that I misunderstood the page on `@use` and that it's only supported by Dart Sass right now, not LibSass, so `@import` is not discouraged in this case.